# How to set to get message using IBM MQ Client from remote IBM MQ Server

Tags: queue, websphere, ibm-mq, mq

I am setting queue messaging system between IBM MQ Server and IBM MQ Client.

I already setup connection IBM MQ Server and IBM MQ Client.

In MQ server queue, there are some messages.
And I can get those messages using mq commend.

```
> amqsgetc Server_Queue_name
```

But this is just sample commend. And Once I order this commend, all messages are not put in the local queue.
I want to get messages from MQ Server and put them into my local queue in the MQ Client.

How can I set it up when there is a message at the MQ Server Queue.
Do I need a trigger for it? or Should I make a extra program like batch?

Comment: The MQ Client does not have queues. It is a remote application call to your MQ Server queue manager that hosts the queues.

Comment: Thank you so much. Then How can I store data from MQ Server? As I write , I was able to get the data from MQ Server through MQ Client. But I couldn't store it. Is there any way to store the data on my local side??Thanks again

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the message, and why you want to store it. On the surface it looks like you are looking for basic data persistence.

Comment: If you want to have queues on both your local machine and the remote machine (where you currently have a queue manager), why not have a queue manager on both machines?

Comment: @MoragHughson Hmmm.... do you mean that if I have a queue manager on my Client side, then I can store data??

Comment: If you have a queue manager on your local machine (I'll avoid calling it your client machine as it is not a client if you have a qmgr there), then you can use qmgr-qmgr channels to move messages to a queue on your local machine and your application can then connect locally to that queue manager instead of remotely to the other qmgr. You haven't told us what it is that you are trying to do with your setup. Perhaps we could advise better if we understood the use case you are working towards?